# Overloading Method Selection

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

Let's consider the example

```
public class C {

  public void method(String s, Integer i, Object... o) {
    System.out.println("method(String s, Integer i, Object... o)");
  }

  public void method(Object o, Integer i) {
    System.out.println("method(Object o, Integer i)");
  }
}
```

When I execute

```
C c = new C();
c.method("1", 1);
```

I was expecting 1st implementation of `method` to be called but I got this message printed

```
method(Object o, Integer i)
```

I read from the [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) that methods with variable arguments (varargs) are not considered in the [phase 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2) but this comportment is not intuitive for me.

Comment: Your are getting second method executed because it is perfect match. Just pass one more parameter  `c.method("1", 1, null);` then you will be able to execute first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining Method Signature is based on three phases: First two phases are based on matching non-var args method while in 3rd phase,methods with var-args are considered.

> **Method with non var-args will have more priority over method with var-args if both methods seem to be called**

```java
 // least priority method if both method arguments matching with the calling one
 public void method(String s, Integer i, Object... o) {
    System.out.println("method(String s, Integer i, Object... o)");
  }

  public void method(Object o, Integer i) {
    System.out.println("method(Object o, Integer i)");
  }
```

Here is the Specifications :

[Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

> 1. The first phase performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or **the use of variable arity method invocation**. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
> 2. The second phase performs overload resolution while **allowing boxing and unboxing**, but still **precludes the use of variable arity method invocation**. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
> 3. The **third phase allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods**, boxing, and unboxing.

According to the 3rd phase rule: overloading is allowed to be combined with var-args i.e. method with var-args will have less priority

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only sent two argument so the method with two parameters will be executed, send three and the method with three parameters will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to understand one of the Object Oriented Concept (and its Java syntax) of OOP, Polymorphism and Overloading. Anyway by calling

`c.method("1", 1);`

you are actually calling the second method itself which is accepting 2 parameters and not the first one which seems to have 3 or more parameters. the program is actually doing what is suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the first method, use three parameters instead because var-args usually accept one or any number of parameters. So the calling statement should be like this:

```
c.method("1", 1,"any argument");
```

If you would like to call the first method with two parameters only then use implementation like this:

```
public class C {

    public void method(String s, Object... o) {
        System.out.println("method(String s, Integer i, Object... o)");
    }

    public void method(Object o, Integer i) {
        System.out.println("method(Object o, Integer i)");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two parameters, so the 2nd method will be considered by the compiler which is having 2 arguments because the number of parameters is matching with 2nd method, then compiler check for data types of parameters.
But 1st expected parameter for 2nd method is "Object" and you are passing "String".